# how to sort an array how objects in ascending order of x positions

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, sprite-kit, swift2

I have an array of rectangle objects which I've populated in an array `rectangles`. Each rectangle has various properties, texture, position and so on. How can I sort the rectangles array so that the objects are arranged in ascending order of the x position. The x position property is accessible in the following way, for example.

```
rectangles[0].sprite.position.x
```

I am open to a solution to this problem that is faster or more effective than sorting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sort()` method.
`let sortedRectangles = rectangles.sort {$0.sprite.position.x < $1.sprite.position.x}`

Answer (score 2):

`rectangles` is an array with range `(x,y)`:

```
    func backwardsX(s1: (CGFloat,CGFloat), _ s2:  (CGFloat,CGFloat)) -> Bool {
        return s1.0 > s2.0
    }
    let result    = rectangles.sort(backwardsX)
```

Even in one line:

```
let result = rectangles.sort( { s1, s2 in return s1.0 > s2.0 } )
```

or

```
let result = rectangles.sort( { $0.0 > $1.0 } )
```